# How can i encode a string value in UTF-8 in java?

Tags: java, encoding, decoding

For example : 
If this is the name of the string ( Требования.xlsx ) , the encoded UTF-8 value of this string is (Ð¢ÑÐµÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ.xlsx) .

i need the java code that does this

I Used this site https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php to get the encoded utf-8 value

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(myString)
```

Try this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help . I have tried your suggestion

Comment: String fileName = "Требования.xlsx";
  //String decoded = new String(fileName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(fileName);
  System.out.println("DecodeD sTRING"+byteBuffer);

Comment: and it prints  DecodeD sTRINGjava.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=25 cap=33]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

to use URLEncoder

```
you have to import classes using
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
```

refer to this site for example and more info https://www.urlencoder.io/java/

Answer (score 0):

- Just try it with  "UTF-8" and if it is not working try it with "ISO-8859-1"

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new URL( URLEncoder.encode("add your string  URL here", "UTF-8") )
                    .openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```